# PHP preg_replace to replace entire string based on some text matches

Tags: php, regex

I need to replace the entire portion containing some texts in the string below:

`$string='Rich Food Industries is a giant<w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve"> food processing industry situated in Aba,</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve"> Abia state with branches in over </w:t></w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">10 states across Nigeria. The company was established in</w:t>';`

```
$text1 = 'Rich'; $text2 = 'State'; $text3 = 'in'; $replacement = 'new content goes here'
```

So far I have

```
    $word =  preg_replace('~(.*)('.preg_quote($text1).'{1,}) (?:(\w+|\W+){1,}) ('.preg_quote($text2).'{1,}) (?:(\w+|\W+){1,}) ('.preg_quote($text3).'{1,})~su', $replacement, $string);
```

Note that the first match ($text1) is a word, which can be followed by another word or a '<w:>|<w:/>|</w:*>' tags. Then another word ($text2) which can be followed by a word or sets of tags as before, then the last word ($text3). The entire portion of $string show be replaced with $replacement.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Pattern would be `'\w' + $text1 + '\w'`, where `+` denotes string concatenation.

Comment: Try `'~' . preg_quote($text1) . '.*' . preg_quote($text2) . '.*' . preg_quote($text3) . '~'`. It cannot get any worse.

Of course, any regular expression will break the XML, because you shouldn't really parse or process XML with regular expressions.

Comment: Sorry, better try '~' . preg_quote($text1) . '.*?' . preg_quote($text2) . '.*?' . preg_quote($text3) . '~'` with non-greedy matching.

Comment: @AlexanderMashin. Thanks so much. Can you post this as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `'~' . preg_quote($text1) . '.*?' . preg_quote($text2) . '.*?' . preg_quote($text3) . '~'` with non-greedy matching.

Of course, any regular expression will break the XML, because you shouldn't really parse or process XML with regular expressions.